# Why of this strange behavior from my custom bash prompt?

Tags: bash, customization

This is my script for my custom prompt (***.bashrc***):

```
my_prompt () {
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then # set an error string for the prompt, if applicable
        ERRPROMPT="✔"
    else
        ERRPROMPT="✘"
    fi
    if [[ "\$(type -t __git_ps1)" ]]; then # if we're in a Git repo, show current branch
        BRANCH="\$(__git_ps1 '[ %s ] ')"
    fi
    if [[ -n "$SSH_CLIENT" ]]; then 
        REMOTE="${SSH_CLIENT%% *} "
    fi
    if [[ $EUID -eq 0 ]]; then
        COLUSER=9  # root
    else
        COLUSER=112  # human
    fi
    local BKG1="\[\033[48;5;${COLUSER}m\]"
    local FBKG1="\[\033[38;5;${COLUSER}m\]"
    local BKG2="\[\033[48;5;11m\]"
    local FBKG2="\[\033[38;5;11m\]"
    local BOLD="\[$(tput bold)\]"
    local FBLACK="\[\033[38;5;0m\]"
    local FLIGHTBLUE="\[\033[38;5;159m\]" #195
    local FLIGHTGRAY="\[\033[38;5;244m\]"
    local ICON1="${BOLD}${FLIGHTBLUE}"
    local ICON2="${BOLD}${FBLACK}${BKG2}"
    local RESET="\[$(tput sgr0)\]"   # "\[\033[0;39m\]"
    local TEXT1="${RESET}${FLIGHTGRAY}"
    local TEXT2="${RESET}${FBLACK}${BKG2}"

    if [[ -n "$DESKTOP_SESSION" || -n "$REMOTE" ]] ; then
        echo "\n${BKG1}${FBLACK}${ERRPROMPT} \u@\h${RESET}${FBKG1}▎${REMOTE}${ICON1}${TEXT1}\w ${ICON1}${TEXT1}\A\n${ICON2}${TEXT2}\W${RESET}${FBKG2}▎${BOLD}⌘${RESET}  "
    else
        echo '[\u@\h \W]\$ '    
    fi
}
export PS1=`my_prompt`
```

The desired output is like this:

[image]

The problem occurs when navigating history (keys up/down) and sometimes pressing key Home, my cursor is positioned in a place that does not correspond or the text displayed overwrites prompt or the cursor overwrites text displayed. See this picture:

[image]

So, where is the problem? and Why of it? What's the solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you replace the various unicode characters with plain ASCII placeholders?